# Integrate an isolated application into different (Next.js) projects

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, components

The goal is to develop an application (shop) that can be integrated into existing websites. So far, development has been done in React (including react router) and the shop was integrated into the frontend using an NPM package. Now the whole thing should be switched to Next.js, i.e. the routing will change (no longer runs via react-router).

Question 1: Theme: the shop contains many components (Atoms, Molecules, Organisms, Templates & Pages). The website is styled using a theme (scss), which the shop takes over. Is there a way to list all the components so that any styling issues can be identified? This is possible in the shop application via Storybook, but Storybook is not used in the individual website instances.

Question 2: is an NPM package for the entire shop application the right approach or is there a better option?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.